# Hosting azure app api on custom server

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, hosting, azure-app-api

I am working on `xamarin android`. I want to connect my `local DB` to my mobile app. For this i have created a `azure app api` with `swagger`. Now i want it to use it locally i.e. i don't want it to host on azure portal all i want is to host it on my static IP on which I have bought. I have searched for this question but can't find any thing related to it. Is there a way to host my azure app api on custom server?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: _all i want is to host it on my static IP_ - what does this really mean? Your own IaaS VM with IIS? What's currently stopping you from deploying it there? There's no special sauce in Azure API Apps.

Comment: @evilSnobu i don't want to publish my DB on azure portal as it is not free and free trial is just for 30 days